# Fill erased memory with something like assert(false) on ARM Cortex-M4

Tags: arm, microcontroller, cortex-m

I am working on a project where a portion of the firmware is going to be erased before the product leaves the factory. We have a command to erase this factory functionality. No calls should ever be made into this factory space without first checking the status of the factory area to make sure it is intact. But if we make a mistake and do somehow call one of these factory functions without checking first I'd like the firmware to reset in a very obvious way.

I did a small test, and if I call a function that exists in this restricted space after it has been erased (So, branch to 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF) it results in a lockup reset on my micro-controller, which is nice. But if possible I'd like to go a step further.

My processor is an [EFM32 Wonder Gecko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFM32) which uses the Thumb-2 Extended instruction set. So I think I should be able to fill the memory with a repeating pattern of four 16bit instructions. Is that correct? If so, what are some good options for what I can do with those four instructions?

Comment: I believe the Wonder Gecko has a Memory Protection Unit. Have you considered using it to prevent execution from the addresses where the factory functionality was located? A memory protection fault would give you much better control than a reset forced by a processor lockup.

Comment: Just an idea: Fill the memory with the opcode of the NOP instruction. Place at the end an endless loop like `jmp $` or whatever you like.

Comment: @andymango That is a great suggestion. This part does the optional ARM core MPU and can protect up to 8 regions. It looks like I can use mpu_armv7.h from CMSIS to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction that you are looking for is `UDF`, Permenantly Undefined. See the ARM v7-M Architecture Reference Manual for details. This is a subset of the SVC encoding.

T1 encoding: b1101_1110_xxxx_xxxx

T2 encoding: b1111_0111_1111_xxxx_1010_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx

The 'x' above are ignored, you can use anything here and be fairly confident that these encodings will always result in an undef exception if fetched for execution as an instruction. If you use the T1 encoding, there is no confusion about half-word alignment.

Place the actual code you need in the undef handler, and it will be able to act on the stacked PC value (e.g. store it somewhere, or dump for debug) before restarting.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at section A7.7.191 of the ARMv7-m Architecture Reference Manual, pg 471.

Comment: I tried to fill the entire factory range with `static const uint16_t udf_instructions[] = { 0xDEAD, 0xDEAD };`, making the reserved bits AD. I set a breakpoint at an absolute address in that range and tried making a function call to that address. I am seeing it trip a hard fault, (IPSR ISR Number 3), instead of a Usage Fault (IPSR ISR Number 6).

Comment: I can see UFSR fields within CFSR, and it looks like UNDEFINSTR is set. So it looks like this is working properly. I can also see that HFSR has FORCED set.